# what is the use of GEN_ISR in rational rhapsody?

Tags: c++, embedded, rhapsody

I am new to rational rhapsody world. Want to know what the use of GEN_ISR in it?? Didn't get appropriate answer from anywhere I googled, so landed up here. Please help me understand it!!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, `GEN_ISR()` is used to generate a static event. Therefore you should allocate the event beforehand.